# Not able to highlight text in excel in java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

My scenario is to get text from "Status" column and based on text comparison ,I want to highlight that particular cell.Below is my code-

```
   private static void colorSheet(String xlsxFileAddress)
    {
        try
        {
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(xlsxFileAddress));

            //Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

            //Get first/desired sheet from the workbook
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            XSSFFormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
            XSSFSheetConditionalFormatting sheetCF = sheet.getSheetConditionalFormatting();
            //Iterate through each rows one by one
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
            while (rowIterator.hasNext())
            {
                Row row = rowIterator.next();
                //For each row, iterate through all the columns
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

                while (cellIterator.hasNext())
                {
                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                    //Check the cell type after eveluating formulae
                    //If it is formula cell, it will be evaluated otherwise no change will happen
                    switch (evaluator.evaluateInCell(cell).getCellType())
                    {
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                            System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "tt");
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        {
                            System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "tt");

                            ConditionalFormattingRule rule2 = sheetCF.createConditionalFormattingRule(ComparisonOperator.EQUAL,"Extra Rows in new table");

                            org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.PatternFormatting fill2 = rule2.createPatternFormatting();

                            fill2.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.BLUE.index);
                            fill2.setFillPattern(PatternFormatting.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
                            CellRangeAddress[] regions = {
                                    CellRangeAddress.valueOf("A2:A7")
                            };

                            sheetCF.addConditionalFormatting(regions, rule2);
                            break;

                        }
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
            file.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I want that whichever cell has a text "Extra Rows in new table" should be highlighted in blue but my code  is not working.please suggest needful.

Comment: What is "file"? How is it defined?

Comment: file is an object of file class.

Comment: Let me ask you this - what's the point of iterating through the rows and cells searching or the text, if you apply a conditional formatting on the range anyway? You should either try to apply the conditional formatting on the entire range (and then try to find why it doesn't work) - OR iterate through the cells - and when you find the value you're looking for - apply the style to that cell directly (and not through the range).

Comment: [link for your reference] (http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FillsAndFrills)

Comment: Check my answer below - I'm still not sure why you go with iteration+range, but most likely the problem is with not actually saving the changes back into the file.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the problem is that you're reading the file and changing its content in the process memory, but you never write the changes back into the file.

Try replacing:

```
file.close();
```

with:

```
file.close();
FileOutputStream writeFile = new FileOutputStream(new File(xlsxFileAddress));
workbook.write(writeFile);
writeFile.close();
```

Comment: Still not working.File is created but its corrupted ,not able to view its content.

Comment: Yes, if you take a look at the error it says there's something wrong with the conditional formatting. Check why it's failing or apply the format manually (as I suggested above) - but regardless - without the change I proposed here you were not even saving the changes, so I think that's the answer you were looking for.

Comment: You can't write back to the same file while the original file and workbook are still open.  Please see [Java apache POI java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Position 21504 past the end of the file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28097440/java-apache-poi-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-position-21504-past-the-end) for details.  That question was for .xls files, but it applies to .xlsx files also.

Comment: @rgettman - I'm not quite sure how your comment is related to the above...?

Comment: @OferLando It should help with the corruption error with the file that is created.

Answer (score 0):

It can be because of

1. ConditionalFormattingRule "Equal" will work only when it is given like `ComparisonOperator.EQUAL, "\"" + "Extra Rows in new table" + "\""` instead of `(ComparisonOperator.EQUAL,"Extra Rows in new table");`
2. Add this after your `file.close()` in order to write back to the file.

```
FileOutputStream writeFile = new FileOutputStream(new
File(xlsxFileAddress));
workbook.write(writeFile);
writeFile.close();
```